# Outline is drawn incorrectly on Chrome if outline-style is set to "solid" (and not "auto")

Tags: css, macos, google-chrome, outline

I am seeing this behavior for Chrome on a Mac (haven't tested it on Windows yet). 
Also, as this work is for a chrome extension, I am okay with getting a solution that is relevant for Chrome only (does not have to work cross-browser for now).

Issue: 
The browser seems to be drawing the "outline" differently around elements depending on whether the outline-style is "auto" or not.

When drawing an outline around an  tag that is the parent of an "img", for something like this:

```
 <a href="image.com">
   <img class="profile_photo_img" src="imageSrc.jpeg" width="50" alt="Steve Jobs" height="50">
 </a>
```

- If the outline-style is "auto", the outline is drawn correctly. i.e. Chrome takes into account the dimensions of the inner image to render an outline around the  tag. (see the green outline in the screenshot).

[image]

- If the outline-style is "solid" or any other regular style, the outline is drawn only around the outer  tag disregarding the dimensions of the inner child.

[image]

The CSS that I am applying looks like this:

```
.class-name:focus {
   outline: 4px auto #068065 !important;
   outline-offset: 2px !important;
 }
```

1) Is there a way to fix this or work around this i.e. have the browser draw the outline correctly for outline-style "solid" as well?

2) Where should I look to read more about this? Maybe some informal documentation or access to the relevant code?

Comment: Recently ran into a related issue on Chrome on Windows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141865/outline-offset-does-not-get-applied-on-chrome-windows-when-outline-style-is-aut

Comment: Draw your outline on img, I've already seen this behavior with links few times but never yet in chrome, since i avoid this for long :) (to myself: funny how you get habits and never rethink it )

Comment: I am changing the style of the element that gets the focus on tabbing. The "a" element gets the focus, the "img" does not. I am hoping to keep things clean by applying the style only to the element that receives focus (instead of its children etc). Makes sense?

Comment: a:focus img ? doesn't work ? why should it be nonsense ?, you may add tabindex="0" to img if you it to catch focus on click ;)

Comment: Sometimes anchor tags contain several elements (not just one image). In that case, we need the outline to be applied to the anchor tag container and not the contained image only. So I don't want to make a special case for scenarios when there is only one image in an anchor tag. This is my understanding at the moment. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Linking a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975587/outline-applied-to-an-anchor-containing-an-image-isnt-the-right-height-in-chrom?

Comment: oki, i understand about the strict a:focus. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

... Set display:inline-block to your link, so layout is activated :)

test : http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/GFzrs

*I see no auto outline in FF 21.0*

Comment: Thanks for that. It would have possibly worked if I was writing this for a web application. But as mentioned, this code is for a chrome extension that is changing the outline style of an element that gets the focus on tabbing. Since this is applied to any external website, it will not make sense to change the display property on focus.

Comment: Umm, I didn't get your question. On the 'focus' event, I add a class to the active element (that defines the styles to be applied). On the blur event, I remove the class. The focus event gets raised whenever an element get focus - either the user presses the "tab" key to set/move focus, or it is programmatically set using focus().

Comment: This happens in the "content script" of the chrome extension that run in the context of the web page that it is inserted into.

Comment: Will consider setting inline-block to the link if nothing else seems to help.

Comment: Thanks for the details. Do you have a way to check if <a> has a display or a float rules to only overwrite it when it has only defaut inline rule ? I believe if <a> holds different tags for styling purpose, then it has already its layout set somehow

Comment: Yes. This is what I decided to go with finally. I check if the <a> tag is display:inline, and if it has any non-inline element as child. If so, I set the display of the active <a> to inline-block while it is focused (through a class). When the element is blurred, the class is removed. Seems to be working fine so far. Thanks for the help :)