# Outline-offset property jumps to parent component

Tags: html, css, styled-components

I have a checkbox input with a label, all wrapped up in a div container. I am using `styled-components` with React but this is the rough structure of the component:

```html
<CheckboxWrapper>
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <label>Label</label>
</CheckboxWrapper>
```

What I want to achieve is to customize the `:focus` state of the component. By default it is set to an outline around the checkbox, but I want to set it around the whole wrapper. This is my css code:

```css
input:focus + label {
  border-radius: 4px;
  outline: 2px solid black;
  outline-offset: 24px;
}
```

The outline on focus works fine, but the `outline-offset` property is completely gone when I inspect the component in any browser. And to my complete surprise, I then discovered ***it is being applied to the parent component***. That is, the `CheckboxWrapper` now has a solitary `outline-offset` property applied. What the heck?

I found a similar problem posted on [this 9 year old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17146707/outline-is-drawn-incorrectly-on-chrome-if-outline-style-is-set-to-solid-and-n). I tried all the answers listed on that post to no avail (applying `display: inline-flex`, `outline-style: solid`...). Besides, the bug happens also in Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding a way more elegant solution:

```css
.wrapper:focus-within {
  box-shadow: ...
}
```